# Counting the directed paths in a particular directed graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

I want to find out how many directed simple paths from $s$ to $t$ are in the following directed graph $G=(V,E)$.

$$\begin{align}
V=&\{s, v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_n, t\}, \quad n=2k, k \in \mathbb{N} \\
E=&\{ (s, v_1), (s, v_2), \\
&\;(v_1,v_3), (v_1,v_4), (v_2,v_3),(v_2,v_4), \\
&\;(v_3,v_5), (v_3,v_6), (v_4,v_5), (v_4,v_6), \\
&\;\ldots, \\
&\;(v_{n-5},v_{n-3}), (v_{n-5},v_{n-2}), (v_{n-4},v_{n-3}), (v_{n-4},v_{n-2}), \\
&\;(v_{n-3},v_{n-1}), (v_{n-3},v_{n}), (v_{n-2},v_{n-1}), (v_{n-2},v_{n}), \\
&\;(v_{n-1},t), (v_{n},t) \}
\end{align}$$

[image]

In my opinion, there are $n$ directed paths. Is that right?

Comment: According to our definition it must hold $  v_i \ne v_j $for a path. Therefore the paths have to be simple paths. What do you mean by directed paths of length 0?

Comment: Ok then I get that. There are n vertices + s +t = n+2:). How do you get to 4n?

Comment: I forgot to mention. How many paths are from s to t. I am sorry:(

Comment: I added an image. Double-check that it agrees with your understanding of the graph's structure. (I also added the "from $s$ to $t$" qualifier. And "simple".)

Comment: @Blue: Thank you very much:) It agrees on my understanding:) @ bof: I am sorry.

Comment: When I start at s, then there are two possible path. When i get to $ v_1 $ for example, then i have 2 possible paths again and so on.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, No they don't have to be of minimal length.

Comment: The problem would be much easier if the graph were directed. :)

Comment: Ok now I see my second mistake. The graph is directed.

Comment: Next time I am going to think first.

Comment: @Blue But the problem is more interesting if the graph is **undirected**. In that case I get $2^kF_{k+1}$ where the $F_n$ are Fibonacci numbers, $F_1=F_2=1$.

Comment: @bof: It is directed, It was my fault. How do get to $ 2^k F_{k+1}$?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I got $2^kF_{k+1}$ (not sure it's right) for the **undirected** graph. Isn't it just $2^k$ for the directed graph? (I suppose all edges are directed from left to right?)

Comment: Yes, from each vertex you have two edges. I seems to be right.

Comment: Another question to this task would be: How much time does a computer need, who compares the length of $ 10^9 $ different paths within a second, to find the shortest way for n=100. Would this be simply $ \frac{2^{100}}{10^9} s ?$

Comment: Seemed to be a litte bit long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each vertex of the graph, the *level* of the vertex is the length of the shortest directed path from $s$ to that vertex.  So $s$ has level $0$, $v_{2l-1}$ & $v_{2l}$ have level $l$, and $t$ has level $k+1$.  Note that each directed path from $s$ to $t$ much contain exactly one vertex from each level.

Let $s=u_0 \to u_1 \to u_2 \to\ldots \to u_k \to u_{k+1}=t$ be a directed path.  Note that $u_i$ has level $i$.  For each $u_i$ ($0\le i \le k-1$), there are always two possible vertices of level $i+1$ and $(u_i,u_{i+1})$ is always a directed edge in $G$.  Also there is only one choice after $u_k$.  Therefore, the number of such paths is $2^k$.

---

I also thought about bof's proposition to consider un-directed paths.  Here is a proof.

Note that for an un-directed path $s=u_0\to u_1\to u_2\to\ldots \to u_r \to u_{r+1}=t$, there is at most one possible backward movement at each $u_i$ and if $u_{i+1}$ is obtained by a backward movement, $u_{i+1}$ must go to $u_{i+2}$ with a unique forward movement.  Then, we cannot make another backward movement, so we have to perform another forward movement.  Let's call such a backward-followed-by-forward-twice sequence a *looping*.  Observe that two loopings cannot be done consecutively.

Observe also that if we are not at a vertex where a backward movement has just been performed, there are always two possible choices to move forward (unless you are at $v_{2k-1}$ or $v_{2k}$, where the only forward movement is to go to $t$).  Therefore, our path can be represented by a binary sequence of length $k+1$, where $0$ is a forward movement and $1$ is a looping, such that the sequence starts with two $0$, and no two $1$ occur successively.

There are $F_{k+1}$ such binary sequences (since removing the two $0$ at the beginning, you are in the situation of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022451/how-many-n-bit-sequences-of-0s-and-1s-are-there-without-two-consecutive-1s)).  Here $F_k$ is the $k^\text{th}$ Fibonacci number with $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$. There are $k$ forward movements each having two choices (recalling that the final forward movement has only one possible choice).  This gives you a factor $2^k$. Therefore, there are $2^kF_{k+1}$ un-directed paths from $s$ to $t$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your excellent proof:) Thank you very much:)

Comment: In the comments i had another question:
Another question to this task would be: How much time does a computer need, who compares the length of $10^9$
different paths within a second, to find the shortest way for n=100. Would this be simply $\frac{2^{100}}{10^9} $s?

Comment: @Leon1998 Another question? Then open a new question.

Comment: Now that question belongs to this subject. Otherwise it ist hard to understand.

Comment: Also, if $a_k$ is the number of paths from $s$ to $t$ in the undirected graph, then it satisfies the recurrence $a_k=2a_{k-1}+4a_{k-2}$ which we can solve directly, or else substitute $a_k=2^kb_k$, whereupon it is transformed into the Fibonacci recurrence $b_k=b_{k-1}+b_{k-2}$.